# Cast a website to TV from Android app - Chromecast; is it possible?

Tags: html, chromecast

This is what I want to do.

1. Have a screen on my Android app with a few buttons on it. One of them would be the Chromecast icon, the other buttons would just be a few numbers most like (a "1" button, a "2" button, a "3" button etc).
2. When the cast button is hit, a default website is loaded (eg. www.example.com) on the TV. In the Android app, I still just see my buttons.
3. When a number his hit (ie. "1") the website changes, and www.example.com/parameter/1 is loaded for example.

I have been reading Google's documentation. If I understand correctly, I can create Android sender app code to do part 1 and 2. And a receiver application for part 3.

What I am confused about though is how I just get it to load a preexisting website. Surely I wouldn't need any custom HTML5 code for that? All I want to do is load a URL.

Could someone please advise me if what I want to do is possible, and if so point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Despite the fact that you are "sure" you wouldn't need a custom receiver, you do. You need to have something like an iframe and load pages that you want inside that. You then need to send the urls through a custom namespace/channel to your receiver and open them in your receiver's iframe as they are received by your receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The default receiver only loads media URLs.  Video, images, etc.  If you want it to do anything else, like show a website, you need to create a custom receiver.

Luckily, that's rather easy, and they have some good samples on the Github account.

https://github.com/googlecast